Why is joblib's Parallel delayed faster than dasks map block and compute()
This question is possibly related to this one. I have 4D numpy array and would like to apply a function to each 2D slice across the first two dimensions. I have implemented the analysis for both dask and joblib. joblib takes only 0.10 minutes, the dask variant takes 8 minutes. Can somebody explain me why?
Here's an MRE:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import dask.array as da
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from joblib import Parallel,delayed
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ConvergenceWarning
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ConvergenceWarning)

###############################################################################
## Preparation (only to create data)
###############################################################################

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

def generate_4d_array(rng,time_steps=10,brain_regions=15,transitions=50, subjects=200, 
                       time_autocorr=0.8, subject_autocorr=0.6, dtype=np.float32):
    """
    Generates a 4D array with temporal and subject-based autocorrelation, 
    and performs Z-score normalization over axis 1 (brain regions).
    
    Parameters:
    - rng (np.random.RandomState): RandomState instance for reproducibility (mandatory).
    - time_steps (int): Number of time points (default is 100).
    - brain_regions (int): Number of brain regions (default is 300).
    - transitions (int): Number of transitions per subject (default is 50).
    - subjects (int): Number of subjects (default is 100).
    - time_autocorr (float): Temporal autocorrelation coefficient (0 < time_autocorr < 1, default is 0.8).
    - subject_autocorr (float): Subject autocorrelation coefficient (0 < subject_autocorr < 1, default is 0.6).
    - dtype (data type): Data type of the array (default is np.float32).
    
    Returns:
    - numpy.ndarray: 4D array with shape (time_steps, brain_regions, transitions, subjects), 
                      Z-score normalized over brain regions (axis 1).
    """
    
    # Generate base signals for subjects
    subject_base_signal = rng.normal(size=(subjects, brain_regions)).astype(dtype) * 2

    # Precompute random noise for efficiency
    noise = rng.normal(scale=0.5, size=(time_steps, brain_regions, transitions, subjects)).astype(dtype)
    transition_noise = rng.normal(scale=0.5, size=(transitions, subjects, brain_regions)).astype(dtype)

    # Initialize the 4D array
    data = np.zeros((time_steps, brain_regions, transitions, subjects), dtype=dtype)

    # Populate the 4D array with time series data
    for subject in range(subjects):
        base_signal = subject_base_signal[subject]
        for transition in range(transitions):
            transition_signal = base_signal + transition_noise[transition, subject]

            time_series = np.zeros((time_steps, brain_regions), dtype=dtype)
            time_series[0] = transition_signal + noise[0, :, transition, subject]
            
            # Temporal autocorrelation generation
            for t in range(1, time_steps):
                time_series[t] = (time_autocorr * time_series[t - 1] + 
                                  (1 - time_autocorr) * transition_signal + 
                                  noise[t, :, transition, subject])

            # Store in the data array
            data[:, :, transition, subject] = time_series

    # Perform Z-score normalization over axis 1 (brain regions)
    mean = np.mean(data, axis=1, keepdims=True)  # Mean of brain regions
    std = np.std(data, axis=1, keepdims=True)    # Standard deviation of brain regions
    data = (data - mean) / std  # Z-score normalization

    return data

data = generate_4d_array(rng)

# how big is whole array and how big is each chunk?
array_gib = data.nbytes / (1024 ** 3)
chunk_gib = data[0, 0, :, :].nbytes / (1024 ** 3)
print(f"Memory occupied by array: {array_gib} GiB, Memory occupied by chunk: {chunk_gib} GiB")

###############################################################################
## With joblib
###############################################################################

def mixed_model(a):
    '''Runs one mixed model for one region and one point in time over
    all subjects and state transitions'''
    
    # make a dataframe out of input chunk
    df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    df.index.name = 'transition'
    df.columns.name = 'subject'
    df = df.melt(ignore_index=False)
    
    # run mixel model
    result = smf.mixedlm("value ~ 1", df, groups=df["subject"]).fit(method=["cg"])
    t_stat = result.tvalues['Intercept']
    
    return t_stat

def mixed_models(data):
    '''Compute mixed-model for every region and every point in time'''
    
    time_points, regions = data.shape[:2]
    result = np.zeros((time_points,regions))  # Result matrix (1001x376)
    
    result = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(mixed_model)(data[i,j]) 
                                    for i in range(time_points) 
                                    for j in range(regions))

    result = np.array(result).reshape((time_points, regions))

    return result


start = time.time()
result_matrix_1 = mixed_models(data)
print(f"Took {(time.time() - start) / 60} minutes")

###############################################################################
## With Dask
###############################################################################

def mixed_model(chunk):
    '''Runs one mixed model for one region and one point in time over
    all subjects and state transitions'''
    
    # make an array out of chunk
    X = chunk[0,0,:,:]
    
    # make a dataframe out of input chunk
    X = pd.DataFrame(X)
    X.index.name = 'transition'
    X.columns.name = 'subject'
    X = X.melt(ignore_index=False)
    
    # run mixel model
    result = smf.mixedlm("value ~ 1", X, groups=X["subject"]).fit(method=["cg"])
    t_stat = result.tvalues['Intercept']
    
    # return single value array
    t_stat = np.array(t_stat)[None,None]
    
    return t_stat

def mixed_models(data):
    
    # map function to each chunk and compute
    result_matrix = data.map_blocks(mixed_model,drop_axis=[2,3]).compute()

    return result_matrix

start = time.time()

# convert to dask array (overwrite to not occupy RAM twice)
data = da.from_array(data,chunks=(1,1,data.shape[2],data.shape[3]))

# map function to each chunk and compute
result_matrix_2 = mixed_models(data)

print(f"Took {(time.time() - start) / 60} minutes")

###############################################################################
## Compare outputs
###############################################################################

print(f"Outputs are equal: {np.array_equal(result_matrix_1,result_matrix_2)}")


Well as was commented on your previous question, the dask code was only using one core, so it's probably that. How long does it take with python for loops over the subarrays?
